# foreign key constraint error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1005

i have two tables ring and style i.e

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ring` (
  `jewelry_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ring_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`jewelry_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

the syle table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `style` (
  `style_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `style` text NOT NULL,
  `jewelry_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`style_id`),
  KEY `jewelry_id` (`jewelry_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

when i add a foreign key to the style table it give me error i.e

```
ALTER TABLE `style`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `style_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`jewelry_id`) REFERENCES `ring` (`jewelry_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

the error is

```
#1005 - Can't create table './j_jewelry/#sql-2c3b_750.frm' (errno: 150) (Details...</a>)
```

Comment: +1 for well formatted question from new user. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyISAM tables dont support foreign keys. Make both tables InnoDB.

Comment: He's adding the constraint to the style table which is InnoDB.

Comment: @Dan: Both tables need to be InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

For foreign key referencing  the table type should be `INNODB`

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB has row-level locking. MyISAM only has full table-level locking. Consequently, InnoDB supports referential integrity and hence the foreign keys and other relationship constraints.